# Global Query Filter - How does this work?

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

The below is documentation from Microsoft explaining how to implement a global query filter however what is not explained is where the value for the _tenantId comes from. 
Using as-is give an error. 
How to actually implement this? 
Where the use case would be each request would be aware of the _tenantId value

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().Property<string>("_tenantId").HasColumnName("TenantId");

    // Configure entity filters
    modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasQueryFilter(b => EF.Property<string>(b, "_tenantId") == _tenantId);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasQueryFilter(p => !p.IsDeleted);
}
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/filters#example) example also contains a link to [full article sample on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/tree/master/samples/core/QueryFilters)

Comment: Ah, indeed there is. I just glanced over that. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Dead sample link fixed: https://github.com/dotnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/main/samples/core/Querying/QueryFilters/BloggingContext.cs#L8-L13